# Get my output, which is triggered by a pressed button, into a blank input

Tags: javascript, html

So I was trying to build this tool to give each player a role in a Video game. And thats working and all but I now want to get the editable player name in blank input next to the assigned role. This must not be an input but I tought that it could work but i literally have no idea how to do this. In any way. So where do I start guys ?

```js
const otherList = [
  `Midlane`,
  `Jungle`,
  `Support`,
  `ADC`,
  `Toplane`,
];

$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const names = [...document.querySelectorAll('input:not(.name2)')].map(x => x.value);
  const tasks = shuffleArray(otherList);
  
  $('output').html(
    names.map((n, idx) => `${n} => ${tasks[idx]}`).join('<br />')
  );
});

function shuffleArray(inputArray) {
  const array = [...inputArray];
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
  }
  return array;
}

var test = Array("Test1","Test2","Test3","Test4","Test5");

function randomTest() {
  var randomTest = test[Math.floor(Math.random() * test.length)];
  document.getElementById('randomTest').value = randomTest;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input id="n1" type="text" class="name" placeholder="Name 1" required="" value="Player 1"> <br>
  <input type="text" class="name" placeholder="Name 2" required="" value="Player 2"> <br>
  <input type="text" class="name" placeholder="Name 3" required="" value="PLayer 3"> <br>
  <input type="text" class="name" placeholder="Name 4" required="" value="Player 4"> <br>
  <input type="text" class="name" placeholder="Name 5" required="" value="Player 5"> <br>
  <br>
  <button class="button button2" type="submit">Assign role</button>
  <br><br>
</form>

<output></output>

<div>
<br><br>
Toplane
  <br><br>
  <input class="name2" name="randomTest" id="randomTest">

  <br><br>
Midlane 
<br><br>

   <input class="name2" name="randomTest" id="randomTest">
  
  <br><br>
Jungle 
  <br><br>
   <input class="name2" name="randomTest" id="randomTest">
   
  <br><br>
Adc
  <br><br>
   <input class="name2" name="randomTest" id="randomTest">

  <br><br>
Support  
  <br><br>
    <input class="name2" name="randomTest" id="randomTest">
     
    <br><br>
</div>
```

Comment: You want to make have roles assigned but want to change the player name without using input? Use prompt()? Please explain thanks

Comment: so the way that it is now is that it just prints out the outcome when i press the button, but I want it to put the names I entered at the in the blanks next to the role they got assigned to, if that makes sense ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try: editablecontent:

```
 <form onsubmit='return editinput()'>
    <div id="editableplayer" contenteditable="true">player name</div>
    <input id="geteditablecontent" hidden>
 </form>
```

Than js

```
     function editinput(){
        document.getElementById("geteditablecontent").value = document.getElementById("editableplayer").innerText;
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: mhhh and how exactly do i implement that in my given code, I really dont know a lot about coding and someone who knows how helped me with what i have so far :(

Comment: can you explain why not input?

Comment: what? I´m sorry if this is just dumb, but i just want the name appear next to the role, I tought input is the only solution i know. If there is a better one let me know!

Comment: No! everithing is ok.
you can use input with value.
 <input class="name2" name="randomTest" id="randomTest" value="player name">

Or with placeholder:
<input class="name2" name="randomTest" id="randomTest" placeholder="player name">

Comment: but how do I pair this with the button press

Comment: alright, for me its 3am so I will go to bed and follow up on it tomorrow, thanks you for helping

Comment: <form onsubmit="pairfunction"">
.....
</form>

function pairfunction(){
document.getElementById("randomTest").value = document.getElementById("n1").value;
}

or n2, n3 you should add id for each one of them.